# Que veut dire « vous êtes l'exactitude en personne ! » ?

Tags: sens

Cette phrase est tirée du dialogue suivant:

> X: Vous m'attendiez, Monsieur? J'espère que je ne suis pas en retard.
>   Y: Non, mon cher, vous êtes l'exactitude en personne! Allons au service des ventes.

(Et connaissez-vous un équivalent en langue anglaise ?)

Comment: I rephrased your question slightly, because translation as such is off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 6):

L'« exactitude » est à prendre au sens de la ponctualité, elle fait référence au fait que la personne n'est pas en retard. Elle serait (prétendument) pile à l'heure.

Ce n'est pas une formulation des plus ordinaires. C'est très clairement une figure de style, et on peut parler d'hyperbole. Le sens n'est donc pas à prendre littéralement. Un autre façon de dire la même chose serait « vous êtes l'incarnation même de la ponctualité » (*you are the embodiment of punctuality*).